# using Android ExpandableLayout Library

Tags: java, android, xml

im Trying to use android Expandable List in My Project

I have a problem, All Rows in My ListView Have the same Items, which is a Edittext and an button, 
But I want to have specific Items for each row,
the main problem is how to set a specific content for each row in my list view?

here is the Codes if its needed:

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.andexert.expandablelayout;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

import com.andexert.expandablelayout.library.ExpandableLayoutListView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private final String[] array = {"World", "Awesome", "Android", "is", "Awesome", "World", "Android", "is", "Awesome", "World", "Android", "is", "Awesome", "World", "Android", "is", "Awesome"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,      R.layout.view_row, R.id.header_text, array);
    final ExpandableLayoutListView expandableLayoutListView =     (ExpandableLayoutListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

    expandableLayoutListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:expandable="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="right"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<com.andexert.expandablelayout.library.ExpandableLayout
    android:id="@+id/first"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#e74c3c"
    android:gravity="right"
    expandable:contentLayout="@layout/view_content"
    expandable:headerLayout="@layout/view_header" />

<com.andexert.expandablelayout.library.ExpandableLayoutListView
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_below="@+id/first"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

view_content.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:hint="Hello World !"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:background="#c0392b"/>

<Button
    android:layout_below="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="click ME !"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

view_header.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="right" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/header_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:text="ExpandableLayout Header!"
    android:gravity="center"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

view_row.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:expandable="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="right" >

<com.andexert.expandablelayout.library.ExpandableLayoutItem
    android:id="@+id/row"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#e74c3c"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    expandable:contentLayout="@layout/view_content"
    expandable:headerLayout="@layout/view_header" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: No, we won't write your code for you.

Comment: @Unihedro sorry it seems my question was not clear! i didnt say write the code for me! i said i have no idea how to set an specific content for each row in my list view!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for having different layout for each row you have to write a Custom Listview Adapter and override `getViewTypeCount()` method in adapter and return how many types of view you are having.

Then you also need to override `getItemViewType(int position)` method in adapter and provide a value ranging from 0..n-1 where n is value returned from `getViewTypeCount()` previously.

Then finally you need to override `getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)` and based on type you can decide which view you need for a given position.

There inside `getView()` inflate different layouts having different implementation of xml tag [`ExpandableLayoutItem`](https://github.com/traex/ExpandableLayout/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/andexert/expandablelayout/library/ExpandableLayout.java) having their implementation for

```
expandable:headerLayout="@layout/view_header"
expandable:contentLayout="@layout/view_content"
```

for the most part you should be familiar with inflating [Multiple Layouts in list view](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2014/08/android-listview-with-multiple-row.html) other things are simple.

**EDIT**

Here is also a famous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4777306/2319390) I have just came across . A good example is also given [here](http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296)

Njoy!